# Platform IO :undefined reference to `init'/[.pio\build\uno\firmware.elf] Error 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, platformio

I use visual studio code for programing arduino uno using platform io. But when I build my code there is no mistake I seen on problem. there is no error script on there. but on terminal says like this:

> Executing task: C:\Users\ridho.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run <

### Processing uno (platform: atmelavr; board: uno; framework: arduino)

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option

CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/atmelavr/uno.html

PLATFORM: Atmel AVR 2.1.0 > Arduino Uno

HARDWARE: ATMEGA328P 16MHz, 2KB RAM, 31.50KB Flash

DEBUG: Current (simavr) On-board (simavr)

PACKAGES:

- framework-arduino-avr 5.0.0
- toolchain-atmelavr 1.50400.190710 (5.4.0)

LDF: Library Dependency Finder ->

LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft

Found 6 compatible libraries

Scanning dependencies...

No dependencies

Building in release mode

Linking .pio\build\uno\firmware.elf

C:\Users\ridho\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrKx04Q.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
***<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x0): undefined reference to`init'***
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
****** [.pio\build\uno\firmware.elf] Error 1***
==================================================== [FAILED] Took 1.43 seconds ====================================================
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I assume that the main problem is ***: undefined reference to `init'*** or*** ***[.pio\build\uno\firmware.elf] Error 1***

I have read all same problem like this ask in platform io community ,and professional said that the solution is disable any antivirus. I just have kaspersky antivirus on my pc. I also disable win defender,win firewall. but when I build again. still same. anyone can help me?

this my antivirus that have been disabled by me:
[this image by clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArsTv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this the solution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUfci2AEBNk&t=3s

type this/copy&paste:   %userprofile%.platformio\packages,

you'ill find framework-arduino-avr folder

and then you deleting the framework-arduino-avr folder

Answer (score 0):

just reinstall the VScode and Platform IO 
Do a Clean install.
Delete all the files of the Platform IO and also Arduino files